# How can I style a column of a table, such as coloring a column, specifying the width of the column?

Tags: html, css, erb

I want to style a table like [this](https://gyazo.com/15cbc922ca5dd560584e2212d8adab3b), I mean I want to style a column specifying width based on the data, color based on the data as well.

```
<table class="table">
 <thead>
 <th scope="col">Price of buy orders(BTC)</th>
  <th scope="col">Amount of buy orders(<%=@currency_id%>)</th>
   <th scope="col">Date of buy orders</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
   <%if @buy_orders.present?%>
    <%@buy_orders.each do |buy|%>
      <tr>
        <td class="table-default"><%=buy.price%></td>

        <td class="table-default"><%=buy.amount%>
          <div style="background: blue;"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="table-default"><%=buy.created_at%></td>
      </tr>
   <%end%>
  <%end%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`<div style="background: blue;"></div>`
I tried the code below but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot color a percentage of an element, so you need to create another element to overlay and size that element.

I'm not a CSS guru, but this will do it.

- `z-index: -1;` will place the element behind the default elements
- `position: absolute;` will allow you to position the element in
  relation to its parent (container)
- `position: relative;` creates the parent element that the child need to
  access for its absolute positioning

I've used a simple condition to decide which color class to use.

The second one you will have to calculate yourself from whatever values you are displaying. (Don't miss the '`%`' at the end of the `width:` in the `style`...)

```
.colorMeBlue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.colorMeGreen {
    background-color: green;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

<td class="table-default">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="overlay <%= buy.amount > 100 ? " colorMeBlue " : "colorMeGreen " %>" style="width: <%= buy.amount%>%">&nbsp;</div>
        <%= buy.amount%>
    </div>
</td>
```

Just alter the condition you want to check for where I have used `buy.amount > 100` and `"width: <%= buy.amount%>%"` as examples.

Comment: Thanks,  I could color the column, but as I wrote, I want to change the width of the part of the coloring based on the data. I actually could color the column before, but I couldn't change the width of colored parts.

Comment: Answer updated @RyuNishida, hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you exactly wanna do and what language are you using with HTML. Anyway the %=buy.amount% content should be inside the tag which is styled, something like this:

```
<td class="table-default" style="background: blue;"><%=buy.amount%>
    ...
</td>
```

Comment: I'm using the erb, and what I want to do is to express bar charts using CSS like trade book that is shown on financial sites.